# Will Data Protection feature also secure the sqlite file behind the scenes of Core Data?

Tags: ios, security, core-data, encryption, data-protection

And if not, how could I encrypt and protect my `Core Data` data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW54) the answer is YES, sqlite file for Core Data is protected by default:

> For apps built for iOS 5.0 or later, persistent stores now store data
>   by default in an encrypted format on disk. The default protection
>   level prevents access to the data until after the user unlocks the
>   device for the first time. You can change the protection level by
>   assigning a custom value to the NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey key
>   when configuring your persistent stores.